# Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file i have over ridden

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, xcode5, ios8.1

in my project i have removed the Default ViewController which will be added from the SingleView Template and over ridden with

```
myapiViewController *fst = [[myapiViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:fst];

self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i am getting Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file.
 while running the app

Comment: Are you using storyboard ?

Comment: did you added Class file name as ViewController ....?

Comment: No I use coding I think I have not Class as ViewController